# aoutofocus to the next edit text field

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am using edit text view and want to move to the next text field automatically when max length is achieved
like in xml 

how can move to next text field 
either from xml or from code 
any help/suggestion will be most welcomed 
Usman Kurd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TextWatcher with your edit text and when your edit text will cross the max limit you can request the focus to your text box .

```
EditText edit= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.myedit);

 edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
 {
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    { 
      if (s.length() >= EDIT_MAX_LEN) 
       { 
           text.requestFocus(); 
       }
     }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int count, int after) {
    }
});
```

**I hope it helps you.**